# Dynamic programming table - Finding the minimal cost to break a string

Tags: string, algorithm, dynamic-programming

> A certain string-processing language offers a primitive operation
>   which splits a string into two pieces. Since this operation involves
>   copying the original string, it takes n units of time for a string of
>   length n, regardless of the location of the cut. Suppose, now, that
>   you want to break a string into many pieces.
>
> The order in which the breaks are made can affect the total running
>   time. For example, suppose we wish to break a 20-character string (for
>   example "abcdefghijklmnopqrst") after characters at indices 3, 8, and
>   10 to obtain for substrings: "abcd", "efghi", "jk" and "lmnopqrst". If
>   the breaks are made in left-right order, then the first break costs 20
>   units of time, the second break costs 16 units of time and the third
>   break costs 11 units of time, for a total of 47 steps. If the breaks
>   are made in right-left order, the first break costs 20 units of time,
>   the second break costs 11 units of time, and the third break costs 9
>   units of time, for a total of only 40 steps. However, the optimal
>   solution is 38 (and the order of the cuts is 10, 3, 8).

The input is the length of the string and an ascending-sorted array with the cut indexes. I need to design a dynamic programming table to find the minimal cost to break the string and the order in which the cuts should be performed.

I can't figure out how the table structure should look (certain cells should be the answer to certain sub-problems and should be computable from other entries etc.). Instead, I've written a recursive function to find the minimum cost to break the string: `b0, b1, ..., bK` are the indexes for the cuts that have to be made to the (sub)string between `i` and `j`.

```
totalCost(i, j, {b0, b1, ..., bK}) = j - i + 1 + min {
                                              totalCost(b0 + 1, j, {b1, b2, ..., bK}),
  totalCost(i, b1, {b0                   }) + totalCost(b1 + 1, j, {b2, b3, ..., bK}),
  totalCost(i, b2, {b0, b1               }) + totalCost(b2 + 1, j, {b3, b4, ..., bK}),
  ....................................................................................
  totalCost(i, bK, {b0, b1, ..., b(k - 1)})
} if k + 1 (the number of cuts) > 1,
j - i + 1 otherwise.
```

Please help me figure out the structure of the table, thanks!

Comment: I have solved the first question using a recursive function but is not actually what I have to do.

Comment: The question is not clear, You have n i.e the length of the string, you want to cut it into m parts, you want to identify which indexes to cut at?

Comment: I've updated the post with a better example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example we have a string of length `n = 20` and we need to break it in positions `cuts = [3, 8, 10]`. First of all let's add two fake cuts to our array: `-1` and `n - 1` (to avoid edge cases), now we have `cuts = [-1, 3, 8, 10, 19]`. Let's fill table `M`, where `M[i, j]` is a minimum units of time to make all breaks between `i`-th and `j`-th cuts. We can fill it by rule: `M[i, j] = (cuts[j] - cuts[i]) + min(M[i, k] + M[k, j]) where i < k < j`. The minimum time to make all cuts will be in the cell `M[0, len(cuts) - 1]`. Full code in python:

```py
# input
n = 20
cuts = [3, 8, 10]
# add fake cuts
cuts = [-1] + cuts + [n - 1]
cuts_num = len(cuts)
# init table with zeros
table = []
for i in range(cuts_num):
    table += [[0] * cuts_num]
# fill table
for diff in range(2, cuts_num):
    for start in range(0, cuts_num - diff):
        end = start + diff
        table[start][end] = 1e9
        for mid in range(start + 1, end):
            table[start][end] = min(table[start][end], table[
                                    start][mid] + table[mid][end])
        table[start][end] += cuts[end] - cuts[start]
# print result: 38
print(table[0][cuts_num - 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you may feel easier to follow when everything is 1-based (same as DPV Dasgupta Algorithm book problem 6.9, and same as UdaCity Graduate Algorithm course initiated by GaTech), following is the python code that does the equivalent thing with the previous python code by Jemshit and Aleksei. It follows the chain multiply (binary tree) pattern as taught in the video lecture.

```python
import numpy as np
# n is string len, P is of size m where P[i] is the split pos that split string into [1,i] and [i+1,n] (1-based)
def spliting_cost(P, n):
    P = [0,] + P + [n,]  # make sure pos list contains both ends of string
    m = len(P)
    P = [0,] + P  # both C and P are 1-base indexed for easy reading
    C = np.full((m+1,m+1), np.inf)
    for i in range(1, m+1): C[i, i:i+2] = 0  # any segment <= 2 does not need split so is zero cost
    for s in range(2, m):  # s is split string len
        for i in range(1, m-s+1):
            j = i + s
            for k in range(i, j+1):
                C[i,j] = min(C[i,j], P[j] - P[i] + C[i,k] + C[k,j])
    return C[1,m]
spliting_cost([3, 5, 10, 14, 16, 19], 20)
```

The output answer is 55, same as that with split points [2, 4, 9, 13, 15, 18] in the previous algorithm.